Understanding the behavior of fan
Consider the circuit used for automatic activation of a fan:

I want to understand how this circuit works knowing that the op amps are ideal, so is the BJTs & LEDs and the Rth is a temperature dependent resistance.

First, there is only 1 BJT (BJTs?). Second, Cite the source of the original schematic.

haha the source is an previous year EE exam for my school i cant even link it because everyone needs my university account to even access the files @MOSFET

Rth and R1 form a voltage divider that creates a voltage at the opamp's inverting input that is proportional to temperature (sign unknown, depends on Rth's coefficient).
There is no negative feedback to the opamp since it is being used as a comparator. When the voltage at the non-inverting input is higher than the voltage at the inverting input, the output will be +12V (assuming ideal behavior). When the voltage at the inverting input is higher than the voltage at the non-inverting input, the output will be 0V.
The voltage at the opamp's non-inverting input has a little bit of hysteresis from the action of the output and LEDs. When the output of the opamp is high, the non-inverting input will see V0 plus the combination of LED1-R3-R2 voltage divider from 12V. When the output of the opamp is low, the non-inverting input will see V0 minus the R2-R3-LED2 voltage divider combination.
T1 is the PNP switching transistor; when the output of the opamp is low, current flows out of the base (Vbe is < 0), which permits current flow out of the collector, powering the fan.  R5 limits base current, R4 limits Vbe.
D1 is the flyback diode for the fan and serves as the current path for the current spike created when the fan suddenly switches off.

Infinite thanks vir!
